UILabel.attributedText with many line breaks causes scroll lag in UITableView
I am creating a UI similar to Twitter's timeline using UITableView.
The UILabel on the UITableViewCell has attributedText for displaying content.
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {
    ...
    cell.label.attributedText = makeAttributedText(at: indexPath)
    ...
    return cell
}

I am struggling with scroll lag that occurs when attributedText contains many line breaks.
When the number of line breaks in the attributedText of the label on the cell exceeds about 20 lines, scroll lag appears at the timing when the cell is displayed.
I identified the cause using the Time Profiler.
I found that the following method occupies CPU resources on the main thread for a long time.
113.00 ms
[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:returningDeviceMetricsOfFirstLine:returningMultilineDeviceMetrics:forceMultiline:] UIKitCore

Within this method, the following two methods occupy CPU resources almost equally.
57.00 ms
-[UlLabel _boundingRectWithAttributedString:size:options:context:] UIKitCore

55.00 ms
-[UlLabel_drawWithAttributedString:rect:options:context:] UIKitCore

But I'm not sure what to do next.
Please tell me anything that can be done to improve the performance of this method.


Try profile testing with fixed-height rows. If that reduces the lag, you could try cacheing the row heights ... possibly calculating the heights during your "fetch new records" process (assuming you're fetching n-records at a time).
